# Every cyclic group with order > 2 has at least 2 distinct generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

> Every cyclic group with order > 2 has at least 2 distinct generators

Here's what I've got so far:

Either order of our group, $G$, is finite or infinite.

Suppose infinite: then our group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ under addition. This group has two distinct generators, therefore so does $G$.

Suppose finite: Then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_n$ under addition modulo $n$.  We know order of $G$ is $\geqslant 3$. If order of $G$ is odd, both 1 and 2 are generators of $\mathbb Z_n$ under addition modulo $n$, so $G$ has at least two generators.

If order of $G$ is even, then both 1 and some odd number between 1 and $n$ are generators. How do we determine this odd number?

Does this look like I'm on the right track?

Comment: If $G$ is a group, how does the order of an element $g\in G$ relate to the order of its inverse $g^{-1}$?

Comment: For finite case, you don't need to separate in odd or even, because if n>2, then at least, both <1> and <n-1> are generators. Note that n-1 and n are always relative primes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: if $a\in G$
  is a generator, than also $a^{-1}$
  (they have the same order).

Comment: I think I'm being obtuse, but I don't see why they have to have the same order.  I get that a^-1 can't have order greater than a (since a has order = number of elements in G), but why can't a^-1 have a smaller order than a?

Comment: Denote $ord(a)=n$, than $a^n=1$. so $a^{-n}
 =1$, therefore $(a^{-1}
 )^n=1$. If $ord(a^{-1}
 )=m<n$ than $a^{-m}
 =1$ so $a^m=1$, which is a contradiction (n is minimal)

Comment: to be clear, in the first part a^n = 1 => a^-n = 1 because (a^n)(a^-n) = 1 by def, and we have a^n = 1.  yes?

Comment: Yes. You can prove it many ways - try assume by contradiction (Than it will become an obvious claim).

Answer (score 3):

Let $g$ be a generator of $G$ then $|g|=|G|=m$. Take a number $k$ relatively prime to $m$ then $a^k$ is also a generator of $G$. So it has exactly $\phi (m)$ generators. (the number of numbers relatively prime to $m$ smaller than $m$)

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove that $\varphi(m)\ge2$ for $m\gt2$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.  But for $p$ prime, $\varphi(p^n)=p^n-p^{n-1}$,  by counting.  And by the Chinese remainder theorem, $\varphi$ is multiplicative.  The result follows.

Answer (score 0):

For finite case, let $G=\{e,a,...,a^{n-1}\}$, you don't need to separate for odd or even, because if $n>2$, then at least, both $a$ and $a^{n-1}$ are distinct generators for $G$. Note that $n-1$ and $n$ are always relative primes, so their gcd is 1. So we have $<a>=<a^{n-1}>=G$