# Proving or disproving that a nonidentity cyclic group has at least two generators.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, finitely-generated

I had trouble proving that a nonidentity cyclic group has at least two generators, but I am starting to think that it has to be disproven. Would I have to disprove it by showing that any cyclic group has at least two generators besides the identity?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What about a cyclic group with only two elements?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

A cyclic group of order $n$ has $\varphi(n)$ generators, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.  For $n\ge3$, $\varphi(n)\ge2$.

Answer (score 0):

> [A] nonidentity cyclic group has at least two generators.

The statement is false. Consider the cyclic group of two elements, given by the presentation $$\langle a\mid a^2\rangle,$$ also known as $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ through isomorphisms (where $a\mapsto [1]_2$). This has exactly one generator.

---

As pointed out in the [comment by @Bernard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625891/proving-or-disproving-that-a-nonidentity-cyclic-group-has-at-least-two-generator/3625902#comment7452535_3625902), the statement is true of cyclic groups of order at least three. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/688972/104041).)

Comment: However it is true  for a cyclic group of order $\ge 3$.

Comment: Thank you, @Bernard; I have edited the question accordingly.